# AgGrid filterParams partial selection of checkboxes on intial load

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am using AgGrid.
Can someone please help me with the partial selection of checkboxes on initial load.
Please refer the image attached.
[image: partially selected filers on initial load]

What I have done so far

```
export default function tableItems(props) {
return [
{
  headerName: "Items",
  filter: "agSetColumnFilter",
  filterParams: {
    values: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
    buttons: ["clear", "apply"],
    closeOnApply: true,
    /// here I'm trying to achive some default selected values, but no luck
    defaultOption: ["2", "3", "4", "5"],
  },
  sortable: true,
},
```

]
}

```
<AgGrid
 columnDefs={tableItems(props)}
/>
```